# Sybase ASE create foreign key constraint ignoring case

Tags: sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying to get same functionality out of `ASE 15.5` that exists in `MSSQL 2008` in terms of case insensitivity.

Sort order has to remain binary for the application to work in standard mode, however new tables - enhancement to the product have foreign keys, and I'd like for them to be case insensitive.

That is, if `tableA` has a value `ABC`, than `tableB` should be able to have foreign key on `tableA` and insert value `aBc`.

I was able to solve similar issue with indexing, by doing this:

```
create nonclustered index myindex on mytable(**upper**(mycolumn))
```

And index now gets used for doing case-insensitive matching, if I do:

```
select * from mytable where upper(mycolumn) = upper('My Value')
```

But I can't figure out how to do case-insensitive foreign key.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to write an update and an insert trigger on the new table that does the appropriate checks against the parent table columns.  [Chapter 20](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/pdf/sqlug.pdf) of the Transact-SQL guide should have the information you need to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
create nonclustered index myindex on mytable(upper(mycolumn))
```

when you run this

```
select * from mytable where upper(mycolumn) = upper('My Value')
```

in the `query plan` you will see index `myindex` in query plan. It works only on sybase 15